# how to modify packets using winpcap

Tags: c, tcp, winpcap, packets

i want to modify the packets data using winpcap, and send the modified packets to the destination IP instead of the original packets. how can i realize it? can anyone give a few ideas? e.g. which API can realize it ? if possible, a few steps or other documentations are more appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You know that PCap stands for "Packet *Capture*", right? How did you come to the conclusion that you could do something like that with winpcap?

Comment: for winpcap can capture packets, and i have also used it to send raw sockets before, i guess it may be used to modify packet data. just an assumption @NiklasB.

Answer (score 2):

With the use of `Winpcap`, you can modify the packet content by `packet[i]=` any hex value (e.g `0xFF`).

Remember to use `i>13` for data modification as for:

- `packet[0 -> 5]` is **Destination MAC**
- `packet[6 -> 11]` is **source MAC**
- `packet[12 -> 13]` is **Ethernet type**
- `frompacket[14 -> onwards]` is **data byte**

Remember `MAX Ethernet PACKET` length is `1500 bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [TUN/TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) instead of WinPcap to achieve the task you described in your question.  Please have a look at this document:

- http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/using_tuntap_under_windows.htm

Unfortunately it's not so easy to use as WinPcap.  So you might want to take a different approach.  Could you be more specific on your needs so that we can suggest easier alternatives, eg. writing a TCP gateway in Python?  This small utility might be a hint for you provided that you don't need to tweak Ethernet frames:

- http://python-xlib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/python-xlib/trunk/utils/tcpbug.py?view=markup